# How do I correct kivy.garden import error:

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg as FCK

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!", accompanied by the error and a minimal example!

Comment: Have you installed `garden` and the `matplotlib` flower?